# Some derivation in quasi-chemical methods

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry

I recently ordered a copy of C. N. Yang's collected papers and tried to read it from back to back, but ran immediately into obstacle with his first article, which is his master's thesis. The place where I got stuck is attached in the screenshot below.

The expression for $\phi$ (which should $= \log P(w, T)$) in the second to last paragraph in the screenshot appears to be interchanging summation and logarithm from equation (1) in a cavalier manner. Am I reading it correctly? Is this justified mathematically? The [full paper](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1724001) can be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=iN7ICgAAQBAJ&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=A%20Generalization%20of%20the%20Quasi%E2%80%90Chemical%20Method%20in%20the%20Statistical%20Theory%20of%20Superlattices&source=bl&ots=j85lJmzx15&sig=ACfU3U1kd74tef7dHZZn33sJdy-ZeRvTyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2uafh3KfxAhXFrJ4KHUSxAjUQ6AEwB3oECAYQAw#v=onepage&q=A%20Generalization%20of%20the%20Quasi%E2%80%90Chemical%20Method%20in%20the%20Statistical%20Theory%20of%20Superlattices&f=false).

In addition, I don't quite follow the Legendre transform in the same section exactly. It appears to me $\xi, \mu, \nu$ are $T$-dependent, but they are not explicitly stated so in the papers.

[image]
[image]
[image]